# How to manage off-chain data using Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ipfs

Consider a system based on Hyperledger in which there are some organizations.

For each organization there is a Hyperledger Fabric (HLF) channel. Each organization will therefore have a certain number of peers.

We would like to share some files with the same logic of authorizations and permissions defined in the operating policies of the Hyperledger Network realized.

Therefore, some files may be shared with some channels but not with others. Other files should remain private only within a single channel.

IPFS could be a good solution? Perhaps by encrypting the data and providing the decryption keys only to those who are allowed to do so? Is there a better way to share files than IPFS?

IPFS is only a proposal. The goal is to share files between organizations using the same authorization and permission logic defined in Hyperledger.

What could be a good solution in this case?

Comment: I think this question is too broad. There is no standard or anything similar that says "this is better" or "this is how you should do this". As a consequence anyone can have its own opinion about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at private data.

It is propagated by gossip protocol(the orderer dont see this), stored in a sideDB, can be purged and you can create policies for that.

Since Fabric stores values as byte arrays you can put any data on that even files.

Take a look at:
[Private Data Documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data/private-data.html)